# How to use the value of a for variable driver.find_element_by_id

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I have below code:

```
for i in range(69,96,1):
    loztreeid = "loztree_" + str(i) + "_check"
    driver.find_element_by_id(loztreeid).click()
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

I need to click on the ID named `loztree_69_check` to `loztree_95_check`. While I'm trying with above code it gives me below error:

> File "gpsdemo.py", line 41
>   driver.find_element_by_id(loztreeid).click()

Comment: Exception stack trace please ?

Comment: for i in range(69,96,1):
 driver.find_element_by_id('loztree_' + str(i) + '_check').click()

Answer (score 1):

I've found a way, tried with below code and its working fine:

```
for i in range(69,96,1):
driver.find_element_by_id('loztree_' + str(i) + '_check').click()
```

I don't know why double quote (`"`) doesn't work, just change to a single quote (`'`).